# Dark Mode not working which i built in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

Actually I was building a notepad, I made a button which will inter change the color of text widget. But its not working nor it giving an error. Can someone explain why this is not working with a solution?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()

root.geometry('450x500')
root.title('my notepad')

fonts = ['lucida','Arial']
fg_col,bg_col = 'black','white'

def darkmode():
    global fg_col,bg_col
    fg_col,bg_col='white','black'

Button(root,text='DARK Theme',bg = 'grey',command=darkmode).pack()

text = Text(root,font =(f'{fonts[0]}',18,'bold'),foreground = fg_col,background=bg_col).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Changing the value of a variable doesn't retroactively change everything that variable was ever used for.  You need to explicitly tell the widget to use the new values: `text.config(foreground = fg_col,background=bg_col)` for example.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It looks like it's setting the colors, but you aren't using the colors to update the widget.

Answer (score 2):

Just prepare the 2 modes and use them as `kwargs`. I got you started with something more encompassing than just foreground and background colors.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('450x500')
root.configure(bg='grey60')
root.title('my notepad')

#prepare base kwargs
common = dict(
    font               = 'arial 18 bold',
    borderwidth        = 0,
    wrap               = 'word',    #or 'char', 'none'
    relief             = 'flat',
    tabs               = '1c',
    highlightthickness = 2,
    insertwidth        = 4,         #fat caret
    insertofftime      = 600,       #caret slow blink
    insertontime       = 1200,
    padx               = 10,        #thick padding
    pady               = 10,
    blockcursor        = False      #make True for really fat cursor
)

#prepare light kwargs
lightmode = dict(
    foreground          = 'black',
    background          = 'white',
    insertbackground    = 'black',  #caret color
    selectforeground    = 'white',  #when text is selected
    selectbackground    = 'black',  #~
    highlightbackground = 'gray40', #highlight color when Text does NOT have focus
    highlightcolor      = 'gray80', #highlight color when Text has focus
)

#prepare dark kwargs
darkmode = dict(
    foreground          = 'white',
    background          = 'black',
    insertbackground    = 'white',  #caret color
    selectforeground    = 'black',  #when text is selected
    selectbackground    = 'white',  #~
    highlightbackground = 'gray80', #highlight color when Text does NOT have focus
    highlightcolor      = 'gray40', #highlight color when Text has focus
)

#not used but acts as an example 
#that you can just keep copy/pasting these things
#and changing values
mcdonaldsmode = dict(
    foreground          = 'yellow',
    background          = 'red',
    insertbackground    = 'yellow',  #caret color
    selectforeground    = 'red',     #when text is selected
    selectbackground    = 'yellow',  #~
    highlightbackground = 'red',     #highlight color when Text does NOT have focus
    highlightcolor      = 'yellow',  #highlight color when Text has focus
)

#toggle modes
def toggle():
    text.basemode = not text.basemode
    text.configure(**lightmode) if text.basemode else text.configure(**darkmode) 
        
tk.Button(root, text='Switch Theme', bg='grey60', fg='grey100', command=toggle).pack(anchor='e')

text = tk.Text(root, **lightmode, **common)
text.basemode = True #invent a switch to toggle
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the variables `fg_col,bg_col` you should configure the widget:

```
def darkmode():
    text.config(foreground="white", background='black')
```

Comment: Also move `text.pack()` to a separate line, or `text` will be `None`, not the actual Text Field.

Comment: thanks i already tried it but has not pack text seperatly